# Spring Client Configuration

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I am relatively new to Java. I have some code which does this:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate()
{
    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
}

@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory()
{
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());
    //some config...
    return factory;
}
@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient()
{
    //some config here too..
}
```

I don't understand why `RestTemplate` needs `ClientHttpRequestFactory` that creates `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` that uses `HttpClient`. The documentation just says that one uses another but does not say what they do? what each of these represent in "real" world(`http` world) and what do they do special apart from each other? why do we need them to wrap one over another(example why not create `RestTemplate` and configure it all in it's class)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring the RestTemplate is a default object for communicating with Http/REST urls.

The RestTemplate by default uses a Java / JDK (internal) based http client (a piece of software for talking to http servers). If you want to use a different HTTP client like [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/), Netty, and [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) you can provide the RestTemplate object with a different ClientHttpRequestFactory instance. You do not have to do this, but you can.

Just specifying:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

might be enough for your scenario. If you use Spring Boot a rest template is already available. You can use:

```
@Autorwired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

and it will be available to your Spring managed object.

If you want to use a different Http Client like Apache HttpComponents client all you need to do is define your own template:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
}
```

The the factory has a default constructor for setting up the correct httpClient for a specific http client, so you do not have to do that yourself.

The code is structured in such a way that it makes it easy for other http client libraries to create their own implementation of an ClientHttpRequestFactory, which makes it very extensible compared to specifying it all just in the RestTemplate. For instance it's also possible to switch to a different kind of ClientHttpRequestFactory. Take a look at for instance the [BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory.html). It's a different implementation, but can be setup pretty easily because the way it's setup right now.

Comment: So @Jeroen, _restTemplate_ is the Spring client, _ClientHttpRequestFactory_ is the request from Apache, _HttpClient_ is the speciffic client impl from Apache. Did I got it right?

Comment: RestTemplate is indeed the Spring client used for doing Http requests (so you do not have to care that much about the underlying library). ClientHttpRequestFactory is a factory class (design pattern) that will create a specific client with some settings (readTimeouts, etc). HttpClient is indeed the actual specific client (Apache Http Client in the above case).